# How to fix a syntax error when it says invalid character in identifier

Tags: python

I just began to learn python and there is a syntax error which I can not fix when I doing my latest project.

```
def adding_report():
    report_value = input('Input an integer to add to the total or "Q" to quit: ')
    while True:
        if report_value == "":
            report_value = input('Input an integer to add to the total or "Q" to quit: ')
        elif report_value.isdigit()：
            final_value = int(report_value) + int(report_value)
        elif report_value.lower() == "q"
            break
adding_report()
```

I expect this function can run and ask me for an integer to add to the report until I enter a 'Q' which can break the loop, then a result showing  the final value of  the report would appear but there is a syntax error when I run this code.

```
elif report_value.isdigit()：
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: elif report_value.isdigit()：
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```py
def adding_report():
    report_value = input(
        'Input an integer to add to the total or "Q" to quit: ')
    while True:
        if report_value == "":
            report_value = input(
                'Input an integer to add to the total or "Q" to quit: ')
        elif report_value.isdigit():
            final_value = int(report_value) + int(report_value)
        elif report_value.lower() == "q":
            break

adding_report()
```

You used an invalid character `：` in `elif report_value.isdigit()：` instead of `:` (It's completely a different character, maybe you used a different keyboard layout?) and you forgot to put an extra `:` after elif.

Answer (score 1):

You have used a [FULLWIDTH COLON](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff1a/index.htm) at the end of the line instead of a normal colon `:`.

Just delete it and replace it with a normal colon (and don't forget to add one where it lacks one):

```
def adding_report():
    report_value = input('Input an integer to add to the total or "Q" to quit: ')
    while True:
        if report_value == "":
            report_value = input('Input an integer to add to the total or "Q" to quit: ')
        elif report_value.isdigit():
            final_value = int(report_value) + int(report_value)
        elif report_value.lower() == "q":
            break
adding_report()
```